# How to create a JS object within constructor and "parent object" as constructors argument?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

The question might sound a bit confusing so I'll let the code explain:

```js
function Foo(arg) {
  const argument = arg;
  const fooPart = new FooPart(this);

  this.printArg = function() {
    console.log(argument);
  }
}

function FooPart(foo) {
  this.parent = foo;

  this.parent.printArg();

}
let foo = new Foo("this is the argument");
```

This is not working for me. How can I solve this problem or better - what would be the correct approach for this?

Thanks

Comment: It is `this.parent.printArg()` ... And you call `printArg()` before it is defined ...

Comment: You have not assigned a function to `this.printArg` by the time you're trying to call it.

Comment: yeah it is like this in the original problem sorry I fixed it.
@deceze yeah works when I create FooPart after defining printArg thanks!
I'm used to Java so that feels strange because the class gets very untidy. is there an other way to do this?

Comment: @BlakkM9 It was already mentioned but just to clarify: On line 3, you call `FooPart` (which calls `printArg`). On line 5, you define `printArg`. You are calling `printArg` before defining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you define `printArg` *after* trying to call it.

The traditional way to define a "class" which doesn't have this problem would be:

```js
function Foo(arg) {
  this.argument = arg;
  this.fooPart = new FooPart(this);
}

Foo.prototype.printArg = function() {
  console.log(this.argument);
}

function FooPart(foo) {
  this.parent = foo;
  this.parent.printArg();
}

let foo = new Foo("this is the argument");
```

The more modern version to define an "actual" `class` is:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(arg) {
    this.argument = arg;
    this.fooPart = new FooPart(this);
  }

  printArg() {
    console.log(this.argument);
  }
}

class FooPart {
  constructor(foo) {
    this.parent = foo;
    this.parent.printArg();
  }
}

let foo = new Foo("this is the argument");
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function Foo(arg) {
    this.argument = arg;
    this.fooPart = new FooPart(this);
}

Foo.prototype.printArg = function() {
    console.log(this.argument);
}

function FooPart(foo) {
    this.parent = foo;
    this.parent.printArg();
}

let foo = new Foo("this is the argument");
```

1. You should call `FooPart` after `printArg` definition
2. You should use `this.parent` to access `parent`

Comment: I guess there is no way to make this more tidy, right?

Comment: We can make it more tidy, yes. I will have updated one soon.

Comment: You should take a look for `prototype` and `Class` or `defineProperty`